# How to resolve Angular Service directly from an Angular Component

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-services, angular-components

I am currently using Angular 1.5.  I am using ui-router as my primary navigation mechanism.  I am leveraging Angular components.

I understand that I can use .resolve on my states to instantiate services which are then passed down through my component hierarchy (mostly using one-way bindings).

One of my components is called literatureList and is used in more than one route/state.  The literatureList component makes use of a specific service called literatureListService.  literatureListService is only used by literatureList. literatureListService takes a while to instantiate, and uses promises etc.

In each of the .state definitions then I need to have a .resolve that instantiates literatureListService.  This means that I need to refer to this literatureListService in each of the .state.resolve objects.  This doesn't seem very DRY to me.

What I'd really like to do is remove the literatureListService references from the .state.resolve objects and 'resolve' the service from 'within' the literatureList component itself.

How do I code a 'resolve-style' mechanism within the literatureList component that will handle the async/promise nature of literatureListService?  What is best practice for doing this?

Code snippets follow:

state snippets:

```
$stateProvider.state({
            name: 'oxygen',
            url: '/oxygen',
            views: {
                'spofroot': { template: '<oxygen booklist="$resolve.literatureListSvc"></oxygen>' }
            },
            resolve:{
                literatureListSvc: function(literatureListService){
                    return literatureListService.getLiterature();
                }
            }

        });
        $stateProvider.state({
            name: 'radium',
            url: '/radium',
            views: {
                'spofroot': { template: '<radium  booklist="$resolve.literatureListSvc"></radium>' }
            },
            resolve:{
                literatureListSvc: function(literatureListService){
                    return literatureListService.getLiterature();
                }
            }

        });
```

literatureListService:

```
angular.module('literature')
    .factory('literatureListService',function($http,modelService){


        // Remember that a factory returns an object, whereas a service is a constructor function that will be called with 'new'.  See this for a discussion on the difference: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/07/07/service-vs-factory-once-and-for-all.html

        console.log('literatureListService factory is instantiating - this will only happen once for each full-page refresh');

        // This is a factory, and therefore needs to return an object containing all the properties that we want to make available
        var returnObject = {}; // Because this is a factory we will need to return a fully-formed object (if it was a service we would simply set properties on 'this' because the 'context' for the function would already have been set to an empty object


        console.log('service instantiation reporting that modelManager.isDataDirty='+modelService.isDataDirty);

        // The getLiterature method returns a promise, and therefore can only be consumed via a promise-based mechanism
        returnObject.getLiterature = function($stateParams){

            console.log('literatureService.getLiterature will now return a promise (via a call to $http)');
            return $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:3000/literature/'});
        };

        return returnObject;

    });
```

oxygen component html:

```
<div>
    This is the OXYGEN component which will now render a literature list, passing in bookList.data as books
    <literature-list books="$ctrl.booklist.data"></literature-list>
</div>
```

oxygen component js

```
angular.module('frameworks')
    .component('oxygen',{

        templateUrl:"frontend/framework/frameworks/oxygenComponent.html",

        controller:function($http){

            var $ctrl = this;
            console.log('Hello from the oxygen component controller with literatureListSvc='+$ctrl.booklist); // Bound objects NOT YET AVAILABLE!!!!!!

            this.$onInit = function() {
                //REMEMBER!!!! - the bound objects being passed into this component/controller are NOT available until just before the $onInit event fires
                console.log('Hello from the oxygen component controller onInit event with bookList='+JSON.stringify($ctrl.booklist));

            };

        }
        ,bindings:{ // remember to make these lowercase!!!
            booklist:'<'

        }

    });
```

literatureList component html:

```
<div>

    {{$ctrl.narrative}}

    <literature-line ng-repeat="literatureItem in $ctrl.books" wizard="fifteen" book="literatureItem" on-tut="$ctrl.updateItemViaParent(itm)">555 Repeat info={{literatureItem.title}}</literature-line>

</div>
```

literatureList component js

```
angular.module('literature')
.component('literatureList',{
    templateUrl:'frontend/literature/literatureListComponent.html',
    //template:'<br/>Template here33 {{$ctrl.listLocalV}} wtfff',
    // controller:function(literatureListService){

    controller:function(){//literatureListService){

        var $ctrl=this;
        this.narrative = "Narrative will unfold here";

        this.updateItemViaParent = function(book){

             this.narrative = 'just got notified of change to book:'+JSON.stringify(book);



         };

        this.$onInit = function(){
            console.log('literatureList controller $onInit firing with books='+JSON.stringify($ctrl.books));
        };

        this.$onChanges = function(){
            console.log('literatureList controller $onChanges firing');
        };




    },
    bindings: {
        books:'<'

    }
});
```

Comment: Please, don't try to describe the code, this never works. Instead, post it.

Answer (score 0):

As JavaScript in reference based, you can crete object in your service and access it in all three controllers that you need.

For Example:

```
function serviceA() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.testObject = {};
    vm.promise1().then(function(response) {
            vm.testObject = response;
        })
}

function ControllerA($scope, serviceA) {
    $scope.testA = service.testObject;
}
```

In this case, as soon as the promise is resolved, all the controllers will get the value of the response and can be used in the partials respecively

Comment: It won't work. The reference to `testObject` shouldn't be changed. Instead, it should be `Object.assign(vm.testObject, response)`. Btw, `vm` name stands for 'viewmodel' and is used only in controllers. It is semantically incorrect to use it in services.